# I need help filling a 2D array so it has only zeros above one of the diagonals

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I have Size x Size array that is initialized with '0' only. I want to fill it with randomly picked integers in a way so it forms a triangle. I tried making a for loop with another 2 in its body, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
pyramid = [[1, 0, 0],
           [4, 8, 0],
           [1, 5, 3]]
```

This is the desirable format

```
pyramid = [[0]*rows]*rows

for i in range(0, 3, 1):
    for j in range(0, 3, 1):
        for k in range(0, i+1, 1):
            pyramid[i][k] = random.randint(1, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the value of `rows`. Additionally, your value of j does not add anything. You need to loop through a 2-dimensional array, so 2 loops should be sufficient.

```
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(i+1):
        pyramid[i][j] = random.randint(1, 10)
```

Additionally, you are initializing a 2-d list, where each entry is a copy of the others, referencing the same object. So if you change pyramid[i][j], you also change pyramid[i+1][j].

To prevent this use `pyramid = [[0 for i in range(rows)] for i in range(rows)]`

Comment: this way all of the elements are being changed, i need the array to look like this [1, 0, 0], [4, 8, 0], [1, 5, 3]

Comment: I noticed that and added a fix

Answer (score 0):

You have an array that is initially:

```
  0 1 2 3
  -------
0|0 0 0 0
1|0 0 0 0
2|0 0 0 0
3|0 0 0 0
```

You want it to be

```
  0 1 2 3
  -------
0|4 0 0 0
1|1 5 0 0
2|9 8 4 0
3|2 5 7 1
```

Notice that if you iterate over rows, you only need to fill up that row until you hit a diagonal (including the diagonal).

So for row 0, you fill up until column 0. For row 1, you do column 0 and 1. For row 2, you do column 0,1 and 2. And so on, so that for row i, you do columns 0, 1, ... i-1, i.

You could iterate over rows in one loop (i.e. row will range between 0 and N inclusive) and then in an inner loop iterate over the columns for that row - i.e. column for row i should range between 0 and i inclusive.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine:

```py
import random

pyramid = [
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]

x = len(pyramid)
y = len(pyramid[0])

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if i >= j:
            pyramid[i][j] = random.randint(1,10)
```